# How do I change materials on parts of huge meshes in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am supposed to work on a huge single mesh in Unreal Engine 4.13.2, imported from Blender v.2.74. My first task is to change materials of some parts of the mesh. It is possible to drag and drop a material into the viewport and apply it to the desired part. I can do that with the material already in use and everything is fine.

The problem arises when I import another texture, create a new material and apply it the same way as before. Suddenly, the material is not in place and distributed all over the surface of said object.

My research showed that I could be in need of a UV-map for the texture to create a material that correctly fits the object (I hesitate using the word "mesh", because, as I said, it is all a huge mesh). Still, I could not find a way to display a UV-map of the texture that is already correctly applied.

What I have tried:

- compared the already imported texture the material in use is based on with my newly imported texture in every single aspect (they are simple 512x512 pixels .png-files, all options are the same)
- re-imported the current texture to see if the .png in our resources is in fact the texture used to create the current material and created a material which could be applied just fine (but was, of course, not the desired motive)
- opened the exact same .png-file, put my desired picture inside, saved, imported and created a material: this resulted in the same chaos as in the description in the beginning.

I am probably missing something very basic, but cannot find it, and would not ask, if I hadn't already put dozens of hours into research. Do you have an idea what could solve the problem I described?

I would rather not make the changes in Blender, because of other changes that were applied to the mesh in Unreal Engine, before I started working on the project.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem and I gave up researching after a while, but I solved the problem myself in blender.

Sadly, you can't fix this problem in Unreal Engine 4 because you either didn't or didn't do UV unwrapping correctly. UV unwrapping in blender is very simple. Here is a link to a YouTube video that shows you how to UV unwrap a mesh: https://youtu.be/r7wC0d2CeSU.

You don't have to create the material in Blender, just make sure that you add a material in blender and then in Unreal Engine 4 you can edit it. Hope This helps!

Comment: Some additional explanations would probably be beneficial.